# Bar chart using java

Tags: java

I was supposed to make a program where it asks user to input the score and show it in a bar chart where the character is *. Here is my code, but I want to make it shorter and concise. Can someone help me reformat this? Thank you.

Is it possible to do it using array?

```
java.util.Scanner;

public class casa2 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)  {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int art, bob, cal, dan, eli;
        System.out.print("Enter points earned by Art >> ");
        art = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter points earned by Bob >> ");
        bob = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter points earned by Cal >> ");
        cal = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter points earned by Dan >> ");
        dan = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter points earned by Eli >> ");
        eli = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nPoints for Game\n");

        System.out.print("\nArt  ");        
        for (int num = 0; num < art; num += 1)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.print("\nBob  ");
        for (int num = 0; num < bob; num += 1)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.print("\nCal  ");
        for (int num = 0; num < cal; num += 1)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.print("\nDan  ");
        for (int num = 0; num < dan; num += 1)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.print("\nEli  ");
        for (int num = 0; num < eli; num += 1)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More compact? Yes. Using array? Yes. But generally better to use [Java Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) rather than mere array.

Rather than repeating lines that vary only by player's name, collect those player names up front. Then loop that collection of names. This way you need not repeat other code lines. In the future, when you add or drop players, you change the players in a single place in your code rather than throughout your code.

If we are defining the players up front, we might as well track their points along with that name. Tracking a collection of such pairings of a key-value is the job of a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html). The player's name is the key, their points number is the value.

We define our map first by using [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V)) because of its simple literal syntax. But that method returns an unmodifiable map. So let's feed that map to the constructor of another `Map` implementation. If we want to keep the map sorted by the natural order of the keys, use a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) implementation such as [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html).

As we collect data-entry of points per player from our user, we update the map with the player's points to replace the initialized value of zero.

To generate our line of stars to graphically display the number of points, we need not write a loop. The `String` class offers a [`repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) method in Java 11 and later.

Some lines of this code could be further combined. But do so cautiously. I recommend short simple lines. This usually makes code easier to read and debug. And this often makes the code easier to optimize by the compiler.

```java
package org.vaadin.example;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Casa
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        // Setup
        NavigableMap < String, Integer > mapPlayerToPoints =
                new TreeMap <>(
                        Map.of(
                                "Art" , 0 ,
                                "Bob" , 0 ,
                                "Cal" , 0 ,
                                "Dan" , 0 ,
                                "Eli" , 0
                        )
                );

        // Input
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        for ( String player : mapPlayerToPoints.keySet() )
        {
            System.out.print( "Enter points earned by " + player + " >> " );
            Integer points = input.nextInt();
            mapPlayerToPoints.put( player , points );
        }

        // Output
        System.out.println( "\nPoints for Game\n" );
        for ( Map.Entry < String, Integer > entry : mapPlayerToPoints.entrySet() )
        {
            String message = "\n" + entry.getKey() + " " + "⭐".repeat( entry.getValue() );  // WHITE MEDIUM STAR is the star character.
            System.out.println( message );
        }
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Enter points earned by Art >> 22
Enter points earned by Bob >> 1
Enter points earned by Cal >> 11
Enter points earned by Dan >> 2
Enter points earned by Eli >> 33

Points for Game


Art ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐

Bob ⭐

Cal ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐

Dan ⭐⭐

Eli ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Map<String, Integer> data = new TreeMap<>();
        data.put("John Doe", 22);
        data.put("Martin Fowler", 1);
        data.put("Calvin Kline", 11);
        data.put("Mario Machado", 2);
        data.put("Entimissimi", 33);

        printHorizontalBarchart(data);
    }

    public static void printHorizontalBarchart(Map<String, Integer> data) {
        String nameFormat = "%" + GET_MAX_NAME_LENGTH.apply(data) + 's';

        data.forEach((name, score) -> {
            System.out.format(nameFormat, name);
            System.out.print(' ');
            PRINT_STARS.accept(score);
            System.out.println();
        });
    }

    private static final Function<Map<String, Integer>, Integer> GET_MAX_NAME_LENGTH =
            data -> data.keySet().stream().mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(0);

    private static final IntConsumer PRINT_STARS = total -> IntStream.range(0, total).forEach(i -> System.out.print('*'));
}
```

**Output:**

```
 Calvin Kline ***********
  Entimissimi *********************************
     John Doe **********************
Mario Machado **
Martin Fowler *
```